# removing read-only access for a folder in windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, file-permissions, read-only

So I have this windows XP box which has a folder. When I look at its properties, it read-only is enabled. When I uncheck this checkbox and saves it, it saves with no messages, but when I open it again it shows the checkbox checked!!

Is there any way to remove read-only for a folder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [All folders in all drives are set to read only on Windows XP and can't be changed](http://superuser.com/questions/182384/all-folders-in-all-drives-are-set-to-read-only-on-windows-xp-and-cant-be-change)

Answer (score 1):

First & foremost, that checkbox is ***not a status indicator***! It is essentially a 3-state switch that affects the read-only attribute *only on the files within the folder*. The 3 states are:

- **Gray Square**: (Default) Leave file attributes alone
- **Cleared**: Clear the read-only attribute on files within the folder when the '**OK**' or '**Apply**' button is clicked
- **Checked**: Set the read-only attribute on files within the folder when the '**OK**' or '**Apply**' button is clicked

If you want to accurately know whether or not the read-only attribute is set for a folder, add the **'Attributes'** column to a **Details** view in **Explorer**:
[image]

In addition, the read-only attribute on a folder doesn't affect file permissions in any way. It only serves to tell Windonws to process the desktop.ini file found within the folder.

Keith

Answer (score 0):

You might not have ownership. These two links should help. I had a similar issue with a client and book marked those links. It fixed his issue. Hopefully it fixes yours.

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=308421

http://www.dougknox.com/xp/tips/xp_security_tab.htm

Answer (score 0):

According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326549,

> Unlike the Read-only attribute for a file, the Read-only attribute for a folder is typically ignored by Windows, Windows components and accessories, and other programs. For example, you can delete, rename, and change a folder with the Read-only attribute by using Windows Explorer.

You can safely ignore the read-only attribute, and the associated check box, for folders, the vast majority of the time. The exceptions would be special Windows folders, which you should not be modifying anyway.