# How to make a file read-only in Windows?

Tags: windows, file-permissions

I set the properties of a file to read only on my desktop

However, I am able to delete the file with no problems.

If I go into the command line, I do get access denied when trying to delete it so I know the read only attribute is there. It's also by running `attrib` on the file.

Comment: Although that's an interesting observation, why does it matter?  What actual problem are you trying to solve? "Why" it's like that is probably only answerable by MS.

Comment: The body of his question doesn't really match the title. I think you're responding to the title and not the body.

Comment: You **can** delete it with the command line.  You shouldn't expect the `del` command to function exactly the same as Explorer's "delete" function.

Comment: I want to protect a file/directory using the Read-only attribute rather than using ACLs

Comment: @Arnold then use the permissions (ACL), that's what they're there for. Read-only is pretty much useless these days, as it can easily just be un-set by a user, especially if there's no file permissions set to prevent them from modifying the attributes.

Comment: ACLs, as in security permissions?  That's exactly that they're there for.  If you don't want to modify the existing permissions, simply add your own "deny" permission instead.

Comment: I was just looking for an easy way for a non technical user to create read-only folders without dealing with the security tab and inheritable permissions. I didn't know the read-only attribute was so worthless.

Comment: It's EXTRA worthless on folders -- http://superuser.com/questions/182384/all-folders-in-all-drives-are-set-to-read-only-on-windows-xp-and-cant-be-change?rq=1

Comment: [This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/68345) shows the observation goes back decades, but provides no insight as to *why*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete a read-only file using the command line, use `del /f`.

If you want to prevent someone from deleting a file using either method, change the security permissions of the file (instead of using read-only).

Comment: OP's asking why he _can_ delete RO files via Explorer without warning or complaint, not how to delete from the command-line. :)